# pymongo getTimestamp without ObjectId

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

in my mongodb, i have a collection where the docs are created not using ObjectId, how can I get the timestamp (generation_time in pymongo) of those docs? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't store timestamps in documents, they wouldn't have any timestamps to retrieve.

If you store timestamps in some other way than via ObjectId, you would retrieve them based on how they are stored.

Comment: alright, thank you, so objectid saving timestamp? i thought all documents save timestamp by default, so I can retrieve it someway even without objectid

Comment: If you want a timestamp in you documents, store the timestamp explicitly.